# How to setup adv7513?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, i2c

I'm setting up adv7513 on altera GX starter kit. Data that I've read from registers after setup is different from what I've sent.

I've tried to divide writes in to the single registers instead of one long transaction, and change the order of writes and reads, but I always read 0x03 from 0x98 and 0x00 from the rest of the registers.

I've used this i2c controller: https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=10125324

and I've made state machine in vhdl to control it, and write data stored in rom

```
if rising_edge(clk) then

    case state is
    when idle =>
        if (beg='1') then
        state <= start;
        else
        state <= idle;
        end if;
    when start =>
        rom_addr <= count;
        state <= lut_addr_i2c;
    when lut_addr_i2c =>
        ena <= '1'; 
        rw <= '0';
        addr <= "0111001";
        data_wr <= lut_data(15 downto 8);
        state <= lut_data_i2c;
    when lut_data_i2c =>
        if (busy='1' and busy_prev='0') then
        data_wr <= lut_data(7 downto 0);
        state <= cleanup;
        count <= count+1;
        end if;
    when cleanup =>
        if (busy='1' and busy_prev='0') then
        state <= next_lut;
        end if;
    when next_lut =>
        if (count = 31) then
        state <= rd;
        ena <= '0';
        else 
        state <= start;
        end if;
    when rd =>
        ready <= '1';
        count <= 0;
        if (rd_delay = 10000) then
        state <= start_rd;
        else 
        rd_delay <= rd_delay+1;
        state <= rd;
        end if;
    when start_rd =>
        rom_addr <= count;
        if (next_rd = 20000) then
        state <= rd_lut_addr;
        next_rd <= 0;
        else 
        next_rd <= next_rd+1;
        state <= start_rd;
        end if;
    when rd_lut_addr =>
        ena <= '1'; 
        rw <= '0';
        addr <= "0111001";
        data_wr <= lut_data(15 downto 8);
        state <= rd_lut;
    when rd_lut =>
        if (busy='1' and busy_prev='0') then
        rw <= '1';
        count <= count+1;
        state <= rd_cleanup;
        end if;
    when rd_cleanup =>
        if (busy='1' and busy_prev='0') then
        state <= rd_next_lut;
        end if;
    when rd_next_lut => 
        if (count = 31) then
        state <= fin;
        ena <= '0';
        else 
        state <= start_rd;
        ena <= '0';
        end if;
    when fin =>
        state <= fin;
    end case;
    end if;
```

[signal tap, what I write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMzUT.jpg)

[signal tap, what I read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBBi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you simply overrun the i2c slave. You should wait for `not busy` in your cleanup state latest after you've provided your second data byte.

Your code does not appear to wait for `not busy` at all?

Comment: Busy is provided by i2c master and it indicates that addres and data were lached in, so I don't think that it's  a problem.

Comment: I do indeed think it is. If you do not wait for `not busy`, you will just overwrite whats there next clock cycle. Note that your FPGA clock is way faster than your i2c clock. Anyway, I'm using the same component and it's working fine for me this way.

Comment: I've changed cleanup to go to the next_lut state after busy falling edge, but it didn't made a difference.

Comment: then you have something else wrong as well. Check out my version: https://github.com/mfro0/deca_mem/blob/master/i2c_hdmi_config.vhd that works. Hope this helps.